# Report/data output dependent on combo option selected

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have an Access DB that has a number of different reports and data exports required. I have created a table containing a list of all of these outputs.

Users should also be able to choose the format, either the report proper as a PDF or as a text export based on the underlying query to a pre-determined directory.

I have created a form with the options:
Report Name - Combobox - cbo_rptName - [tbl_reports]
Output format - Combobox - cbo_rptFormat - [tbl_reportFormats]
Go - Button

```
tbl_reports
ID   reportName   reportPDF   reportQry
 1   Summary      rpt_summary qry_summary
```

How can I get the report to output in the method required based on the user selections in the dropdowns? If not possible, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable with VBA? if so, you could put code for your 'Go' button to output the proper format. Like:

```
stDocName = Me.cbo_rptName       '"Your_Report_Name"
stWhereStr = "<any filter you want>"

stfile = "C:\temp\" & "<your report name>.pdf"

DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , stWhereStr
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, stDocName, Me.cbo_rptFormat, stfile
DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName
```

You would need to use some IF logic to determine what extension name to use. And you would need to translate your Format value into the proper numeric value (you can't pass it something like 'acFormatPDF')